# Aruba 1930 to build Lab Network separated from office network

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, bridge, aruba

Here is the network i need to build for our company lab:

Note: All is centered on the Aruba 1930.

**Network A - 192.168.178.xxx/24**

```
Port 25 on Aruba, SFP+ 10 Gbps -> Cisco SFP+ Gbps -> Router -> Internet
```

This works without any issues.

**Network B - 10.10.xxx.xxx/16**

```
Port 23 & 24, both connected to a Dell 48-port respectively

MUST have DHCP server configured for these 2 ports with daily lease release
MUST have connection to the devices in Network A if entered with the IP of network A
MUST be fed with internet connection from Network A
```

Seems easy enough but I am unable to make this work, either through vlans or through static routes, so I am doing something wrong, or the aruba is not capable of this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You've neglected some details, but let me state some assumptions and go from there.

- You have one or two Dell 48 port switches and are trying to make a lab environment on them
- If it's only one switch, don't connect 2 ports from the Aruba to it. Just do 1. If you need to add in a LAG or something, do that after you get basic connectivity working.

If the Dell switch is managed, just add a DHCP helper to it and point that to your existing DHCP server on network A. If the Dell is/are not managed, then you will need a DHCP server local on Network B.

It would be very helpful to know if the Dell switches are L2 or L3, also.

That's not a whole solution to all your problems, but you haven't actually explained any of the configs you've tried, so I can only guess at your other actual problems.

Some advice:

- Break this into smaller parts, tackle one thing at a time, and build from there.
- this isn't even advice but the way this statement is written concerns me `MUST be fed with internet connection from Network A` - internet isn't "fed" to anything. You really just mean "network B needs a default route to the Aruba".

Comment: Indeed now that you are pointing it out, it seems I was too vague. Apologies and thank you for responding nonetheless!

Comment: We have an Aruba 1930 Switch, this switch has the main role of being and managing Network B and being the Bridge to Network A, ensuring that Network B can access the servers and internet connection on Network A. 

Our lab has workbenches left and right with one Dell Switch each side (not managed) they have 1 connection to the main switch which is the Aruba. 

All the config needs to be done on the Aruba 1930 and that's where my issues are.

Network B should be separated from Network A, hence the difference in IP Class.
Too many at risk PCs could otherwise affect Network A.

Comment: I will add a proper reply with config i attempted later today

Answer (score 0):

Minimal config:

1. 1930: Use two VLANs, one for 192.168.178.0/24, one for 10.10.0.0/16 (I wouldn't use something as large as /16).
2. 1930: Configure IP addresses in both VLANs.
3. 1930: Configure the port towards the router with the 192.168.178.0/24 VLAN as untagged.
4. 1930: Configure ports 23 & 24 towards the Dell switches with the 10.10.0.0/16 VLAN as untagged.
5. 1930: Enable routing.
6. 1930: Add a DHCP helper/relay to the 10.10.0.0/16 VLAN.
7. DHCP server: Create an address pool for 10.10.0.0/16, default gateway for the VLAN is the 1930.
8. Router: Add a static route to 10.10.0.0/16 via the 1930's IP address.